# How to get BasicConstraints extension from Java X509 certificate

Tags: java, bouncycastle, x509

I would like to read the extension BasicConstraints from Java X509Certificate (the certificate implementation comes from default JCE so it is `sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl`).

I wanted to get the BasicConstraint extension value to check if it is CA :

```
X509Certificate certificate = ...
byte[] basicConstraint = certificate.getExtensionValue("2.5.29.19");
```

But this gives me byte array that contains DEROctetString. And after unwrapping it I get byte array with 2 bytes.
However the extension `BasicConstraint` seems to be defined as :

```
BasicConstraints := SEQUENCE {
    cA                  BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE,
    pathLenConstraint   INTEGER (0..MAX) OPTIONAL
}
```

I have already looked at [`X509Certificate::getBasicConstraints()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/cert/X509Certificate.html#getBasicConstraints()) method which returns an `int`. The problem is that it also returns `-1` when the extension is not present.

That is why I am looking for a way to get this ASN1 sequence from X509 certificate to explicitly check this CA `boolean` flag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The valid encodings of the BasicConstraints extension (within the OCTET STRING) are:

1. CA=false: `30 00`
2. CA=true,  pathlen omitted: `30 03 01 01 FF`
3. CA=true, pathlen=0 to 127: `30 06 01 01 FF 02 01 xx`
4. CA=true, pathlen >= 128: using such long paths is so silly I omit this case, but you can work it out using the DER rules if you really want

You most likely have case 1.